# Prove that $\log_\sqrt{2} 5$ is irrational:

Tags: number-theory

Little problem of the number theory.

My proof below:

Comment: Hello! Could you provide us with a bit of context about this question? What is your reason for asking it? Are you looking for verification that your proof is valid? If so, please include it in your question with an [edit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My proof: 
supppose that: $\log_\sqrt{2} 5$ = $\frac{p}{q}$ ⇒ $\log_{2^{\frac{1}{2}}} 5 $ ⇒
  2 $\log_{2}5$ ⇒ $\log_{2}5^2$ 
= $\log_{2}25$ = $\frac{p}{q}$ ⇒ 2^p = 25^q and this is absurd by Fundamental Arithmetic theorem.

therefore $\log_\sqrt{2}5$ is irrational.

Comment: You seem to be writing implication signs where equal signs are intended.

Comment: You can also say that from $2^p = 25^q$, LHS is odd, RHS is even, which is impossible.

Comment: I use the following property: $\log_{a^m} a^{n}$ = $\frac{n}{m}$